# How to get the total result count from Youtube search API?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube data API to perform search request. Trying to get the estimated number of results like shown in the image below:

[image]

How can I do that using the java API? The "totalResults" field in the response json doesn't show numbers above 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Search: list" call. It is described, together with an Java API example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

In the JSON response, you will see `"totalResults": 950225` (for the "funny comedians" query).

Comment: The "totalResults" field is caped at 1M. Search for "music" will give you 1M. But on youtube, you get "About 857,000,000 results".